# How to deploy an object detection model on the Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: python, object-detection, raspberry-pi-zero, tflite

I am trying to deploy an object detection model on the Raspberry Pi Zero. We have chosen the Raspberry Pi Zero because cost is our main issue. When I was installing tensorflow lite on pi0, I came to know that there is no tensorflow lite support for armv6l architecture. The Tensorflow instructions for building the pip TFlite runtime are less than clear in my opinion because I have never used Docker.

**Can you guide me on how I should deploy my yolov5 object detection model on the Raspberry Pi Zero?**

If there is some better option available, then please let me know.

The error I am getting while installing tflite:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run TFLite models wherever you have `tflite-runtime` installed, this is:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tflite-runtime
```

Check this repo out:

https://github.com/karanjakhar/yolov5-export-to-raspberry-pi

Comment: I am not able to install tflite_runtime on Raspberry pi zero.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the error you get?